# Is it possible for only certain elements to be changed if they have a second CSS class?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors

I am trying to make a project where certain elements do an animation when a button is pressed, while similar items that have a different key assigned do not make that animation unless that key is also pressed. I wanted to know if this is something that is even possible, or if I have been going about it the wrong way.

Is it possible for CSS to make changes to elements that have a second class in them? Would vanilla Javascript or DOM manipulation be used? Please help point me in the right direction.

For example, I want to press 1 and the spans with 'A' will the the animation, but the other spans will not.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 7%;
}

table td {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  position: relative;
}

.table-dots {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40%;
  left: 40%;
  background-color: #06f72f;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.bottom-row td {
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="table-dots a-button" data-key="49">A</span></td>
    <td><span class="table-dots b-button" data-key="50">B</span></td>
    <td><span class="table-dots c-button" data-key="51">C</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="table-dots a-button" data-key="49">A</span></td>
    <td><span class="table-dots b-button" data-key="50">B</span></td>
    <td><span class="table-dots c-button" data-key="51">C</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><span class="table-dots a-button" data-key="49">A</span></td>
    <td><span class="table-dots b-button" data-key="50">B</span></td>
    <td><span class="table-dots c-button" data-key="51">C</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Rather than asking if it is possible, assume it is, have a go, and if you run into any issues, come back showing the issues.

Comment: use .classList.length ?

Comment: JavaScript has `Element.classList.add('someClass')`, `Element.classList.remove('someClass')`, `Element.classList.toggle('someClass')`, and `Element.classList.contains('someClass')`. Create the animations or transitions in CSS first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case I would suggest instead of parsing by what elements contain, instead utilize the `data` attributes you're already using. See example below for a quick proof of concept (assuming I'm understanding correctly what you're trying to accomplish).

```js
animateKeys = (key) => {
  const cells = document.querySelectorAll("span[data-key='49']");
  for (let i = 0, x = cells.length; i < x; i++) {
    cells[i].classList.add("example");
  }
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 70%;
  margin-top: 7%;
}

table td {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 2px solid #000000;
  position: relative;
}

.table-dots {
  position: absolute;
  top: -40%;
  left: 40%;
  background-color: #06f72f;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 100px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.bottom-row td {
  border-left: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}

@keyframes example-anim { to { transform: rotate(360deg); background-color: #f00; } }
@-webkit-keyframes example-anim { to { transform: rotate(360deg); background-color: #f00; } }

.example {
  animation: example-anim 2s linear infinite;
  -webkit-animation: example-anim 2s linear infinite;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="animateKeys('49')">animate A cells</button>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="table-dots a-button" data-key="49">A</span></td>
      <td><span class="table-dots b-button" data-key="50">B</span></td>
      <td><span class="table-dots c-button" data-key="51">C</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="table-dots a-button" data-key="49">A</span></td>
      <td><span class="table-dots b-button" data-key="50">B</span></td>
      <td><span class="table-dots c-button" data-key="51">C</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><span class="table-dots a-button" data-key="49">A</span></td>
      <td><span class="table-dots b-button" data-key="50">B</span></td>
      <td><span class="table-dots c-button" data-key="51">C</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```